# Parámetro Class en postman

Tags: java, class, postman

Tengo un servicio REST que en Java recibe como parámetro un objeto de tipo "Class" (MiClase.class). ¿Cómo puedo consumir ese mismo servicio pero desde Postman?

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, cual es el caso de uso de ese servicio?

Comment: ¿Estás recibiendo `Class<MiClass> miClass` en tu controlador o es un archivo? ¿Podrías colocar el método que recibe la petición?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En body hay un apartado que dice binario, ahí puedes colocar el archivo, avisa si funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba